# SQL and XML - Calculation of longest continuous pause

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very specific problem which i was hoping somebody could shed some light on. It is not exactly an error but more so help on the query i need to run to return the desired result set.

I have a table called xml_table with 2 columns; word_id, word_data:

```
word_id | word_data
1       | <results><channel id="1"><r s="0" d="650" w="Hello"/><r s="650" d="230" w="SIL"/></channel></results>
2       | <results><channel id="1"><r s="0" d="350" w="Sorry"/><r s="350" d="10" w="WHO"/></channel></results>
3       | <results><channel id="1"><r s="0" d="750" w="Please"/><r s="750" d="50" w="s"/></channel></results>
...
```

and so on where word_data is an XML String.

The XML String within each row is of the following format:

```
<results>
   <channel id="1">
      <r s="0" d="100" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="100" d="250" w="Sorry"/>
      <r s="350" d="100" w="WHO"/>
      <r s="450" d="350" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="800" d="550" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="1350" d="100" w="Hello"/>
      <r s="1450" d="200" w="s"/>
      <r s="1650" d="50" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="1700" d="100" w="SIL"/>
   </channel>
</results>
```

s represents start time
d represents duration
w represents word
(the number of r tag is NOT fixed and changes from row to row of xml_table)

The idea now is to sift through each row, and within each XML, calculate the longest consecutive duration when a 'SIL' or 's' appears as a in the w attribute and then to return this in a new table as longest_pause (i.e longest consecutive SIL/s duration) with word_id and word_data also.

So in the above example xml we have three consecutive periods where the longest_pause can occur where the total durations are 100 (100), 900 (350+550) and 350 (200 + 50 + 100) and therefore the longest_pause is 900 so 900 would be returned.

I was wondering if anybody could help with this, so far i have:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
DECLARE @ordered_table TABLE (id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, start_time INT NOT NULL, duration INT NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

SELECT @xml = (SELECT word_data FROM xml_table where word_id = 1)
INSERT into @ordered_table_by_time(id, start_time, duration, word)

SELECT 'NAME' AS id, Tbl.Col.value('@s', 'INT'), Tbl.Col.value('@d', 'INT'), Tbl.Col.value('@w', 'varchar(50)') FROM @xml.nodes('/results/channel[@id="1"]/r') Tbl(Col)
```

i.e, I have created a table to put the XML into, but i do not know where to go from there,

Please can somebody help?

Thank you :)

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt at solving this looks like you want to find the longest duration for one XML but the text suggests that you want to find the row in `xml_table` that has the longest duration.

Working with the one XML instance and modified version of your table variable you could do like this.

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<results>
   <channel id="1">
      <r s="0" d="100" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="100" d="250" w="Sorry"/>
      <r s="350" d="100" w="WHO"/>
      <r s="450" d="350" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="800" d="550" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="1350" d="100" w="Hello"/>
      <r s="1450" d="200" w="s"/>
      <r s="1650" d="50" w="SIL"/>
      <r s="1700" d="100" w="SIL"/>
   </channel>
</results>';

DECLARE @ordered_table TABLE
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  start_time INT NOT NULL,
  duration INT NOT NULL,
  word VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @ordered_table(id, start_time, duration, word)
SELECT row_number() over(order by Tbl.Col.value('@s', 'INT')), 
       Tbl.Col.value('@s', 'INT'), 
       Tbl.Col.value('@d', 'INT'), 
       Tbl.Col.value('@w', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/results/channel[@id="1"]/r') Tbl(Col);

WITH C AS
(
  SELECT T.id,
         CASE WHEN T.word IN ('S', 'SIL') THEN T.duration ELSE 0 END AS Dur
  FROM @ordered_table as T
  WHERE T.ID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.id,
         CASE WHEN T.word IN ('S', 'SIL') THEN C.Dur + T.duration ELSE 0 END AS Dur
  FROM @ordered_table as T
    INNER JOIN C 
      ON T.ID = C.ID + 1
)
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM C
ORDER BY C.Dur DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13040)

I added a ID field that is used in a recursive CTE to walk through the nodes and calculating a running sum where `w` is SIL or s. Then fetching the longest duration from the CTE using `TOP(1) ... ORDER BY`.

If you instead want the row in `xml_table` with the longest duration you can do like this.

```sql
with C as
(
  select 1 as node,
         X.word_id,
         X.word_data,
         case when T.W in ('S', 'SIL') then T.D else 0 end as duration
  from dbo.xml_table as X
    cross apply (select X.word_data.value('(/results/channel[@id = "1"]/r/@d)[1]', 'int'),
                        X.word_data.value('(/results/channel[@id = "1"]/r/@w)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')) as T(D, W)
  union all 
  select C.node + 1,
         X.word_id,
         X.word_data,
         case when T.W in ('S', 'SIL') then T.D + C.duration else 0 end as duration
  from C
    inner join dbo.xml_table as X
      on X.word_id = C.word_id
    cross apply (select X.word_data.value('(/results/channel[@id = "1"]/r/@d)[sql:column("C.Node")+1][1]', 'int'),
                        X.word_data.value('(/results/channel[@id = "1"]/r/@w)[sql:column("C.Node")+1][1]', 'nvarchar(100)')) as T(D, W)
  where T.W is not null
)
select T.word_id,
       T.word_data,
       T.duration
from
  (
  select row_number() over(partition by C.word_id order by C.duration desc) as rn,
         C.word_id,
         C.word_data,
         C.duration
  from C
  ) as T
where T.rn = 1
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e184d1/2)

The recursive CTE part works the same as before but but for multiple rows at the same time and it is getting the value for duration from the XML directly using the column `node` that is incremented for each iteration. The query against the CTE uses `row_number()` to find the longest duration for each row.

Comment: The first code executes perfectly and works for that one xml string. The second code doesnt seem to work for me and i get the following error:

Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

However i don't think i made the question clear. I want to find the longest duration for each row and have it returned. So the first row i want the longest duration within that xml, and then the second row, i want the longest duration within than xml and so on so that i have a list with the original word_id, longest_duration (The recursive id need not be returned). Thanks alot!

Comment: @IC3BLAK I have updated the second query to return the longest duration for each row. The error you get is because `word_data` is of type `nvarchar(max)` but it really should be `XML`. There are workarounds to that but you really should change the datatype. Otherwise performance of this query will go from not so good to really really bad.

Comment: @IC3BLAK Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83bbd/2) with a workaround for `nvarchar(max)` that you could use but should not use.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great solution and I completely understand what you are saying, I have created a new table using XML as type to avoid weight carried by nvarchar(max).

Comment: I just ran the code on the table can got the following error: 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.' :(

Comment: I know i need to add the MAXRECURSION parameter but not sure where?

Comment: @IC3BLAK to the end of the query `option (maxrecursion 0)` means that recursion is without limit. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if you could help me with a further adaptation, or infact a reduction. I'm trying to achieve something similar. I want a query to Select a row from xml_table returning it with word_id and word_data if there exists (d > 2000 AND (w = "s" OR w = "SIL"))

Comment: @IC3BLAK use [.exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx). `where X.word_data.exist('/results/channel/r[@d > 2000 and (@w = "s" or @w = "SIL")]') = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like python instead?

You can query the SQL to get the data, then use regular expressions to extract the values from the XML, calculate the value wanted, then insert it back into the results table.

I recently did something slightly similar and decided doing the processing in python was a much easier way to do it if that's possible for you

Comment: I tried using Lua but had no real luck with the luaxml library, I will have a go with Python, any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/  That is a basic tutorial on how to query sql databases in python and access the result.  You will then probably want to look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html to see how regular expressions can be generated to extract information from strings (What your XML will be). You can then take a look at another of my answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317681/python-extracting-multiple-strings-between-2-known-strings-in-a-text-file/16318118#16318118 to see how you can use re.findall() to extract what you want